# How to differentiate between different JavaWS applications from the list of processes in the task manager process list?

Tags: java, process, java-web-start, taskmanager

I am using JavaWS to launch an application, then how to check whether that application is running or not in the user's machine as it's name in the Task manager process list is not what I gave in the JNLP file.

**NOTE.** I checked the task Manager process list but there the name of the process is javaw.exe and all the applications which are using JavaWS  will have the same name. My question being if the user has launched multiple JavaWS applications then how can we identify the process which we want to check? I thought of getting the PIDs of the process but unfortunately there wasn't any way to get the PIDs of the process. I am working on Windows.

Comment: See also [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: Hey @Andrew , i think u got my question wrong .  I just need to find  whether a process is running or not instead of performing some action on starting another instance of the same application.FYI in my application another instance of the same process is not allowed to be launched if the previous instance is already running. I am asking how to figure out a way to differentiate between the processes which are using JavaWS as their names are same in task manager process list . There might be other applications also apart from my application which might be using JavaWS .

Answer (score 2):

> ..how to check whether that application is running or not in the user's machine..

There's no need to resort to examining processes, an inherently OS specific approach.

The JNLP API offers the [`SingleInstanceService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/SingleInstanceService.html) which..

> ..allow(s) applications launched under Java Web Start to register themselves as singletons, and to be passed in new parameter sets when user attempts to launch new instances of them.

Your code will then get to decide whether to update the current app., bring it to the front, or launch a new instance.

Comment: Hey @Andrew , i think u got my question wrong .  I just need to find  whether a process is running or not instead of performing some action on starting another instance of the same application.FYI in my application another instance of the same application is not allowed to be launched if the previous instance is already running. I am asking how to figure out a way to differentiate between the processes which are using JavaWS as their names are same in task manager process list . There might be other applications also apart from my application which might be using JavaWS .

Comment: *"I just need to find whether a process is running or not .."* What apps. are these 'processes' you are referring to? If they are other instances of *your app.,* then it is unnecessary given the `SingleInstanceService`. If it's apps. not created by your app., then what is the ultimate point of doing so? Another way of putting that is, what is the feature you are trying to offer the end user? Your problem description is so far not very illuminating, and I urge you to (re)read the article on the XY problem. If you understood it, it is likely you would be able to describe better what is required.

Comment: *"in **my application** another instance of the **same application** is not allowed to be launched"* Yes, I don't know how to phrase it any simpler. **That is what the `SingleInstanceService` is for!** Actually it covers *more* than that, in that you can decide to ignore any new app. calls (hence only ever having a single process on screen for the application), ***or*** (not relevant here, it seems) you (the programmer) can change the parameters of the current app. ***or** (also not relevant here) you can choose to allow a 2nd instance of the app. to open).

Comment: Thnx @Andrew for all the help :)

Answer (score 1):

On Windows7 you can select list of colums to display in the Task Manager.

Go to `View -> Select Process Page Columns`

and select `Command line` column to be displayed.

You should be able to differentiate between different javaw processes by the command line which includes the class path, main class name etc.